# Ubuntu 12.04 - Pound Reverse Proxy and Adobe Flex/Flash Auth

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, reverse-proxy, flash, pound

First time posting,

I have a completely fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 Client as a reverse proxy gateway to our internal network.  Our setup is we have one external ip but three domains we would like to point to various webservers on our internal network. It's not so much a load balancing issue  or cacheing etc. Merely routing some Client browsers to a port 80 webpage (to adhere to some stricter corporate policies regarding placing port numbers after domain names).

I have gone with *pound* and everything seems to be working fine. Static pages load etc. Everything is good *with the exception of a Flash/Flex based WebClient* for a Digital Asset Management program.

The actual static page loads fine, it is just at the moment of entering credentials, be they correct or incorrect, and hitting login, there is no response whatsoever. Either a rejection or confirmation etc. So the request back to the internal server can't be getting through.

I have googled extensively and there might be a solution in a crossdomain.xml file? Documentation isn't very clear. And we are not the authors of the DAM app, and have no control over the code on the Flash/Flex side.

Questions:

1. Is there a particular config file/solution for pound that allows Flash/Flex auth information to be forwarded?
2. Is there another reverse proxy program (nginx?)that allows this type of config?
3. Am I looking at this the entire wrong way, should Flash/Flex fundamentally not be allowed to have this access?

Comment: Anything? Only 9 views. I'm sure I'm not the first person in the world to want to access some flash content that needs authentication behind a reverse proxy? I can provide pound config file. Syslog logs, etc. If someone is willing to jump on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else,

The fix was that the username/password was submitting through a port OTHER then port 80 (in this case 8080). The trick was to have a Pound listener on that port (8080) and forwarding all requests on that port to port 8080 on the backend server.

This was a pain to troubleshoot but got there in the end (quite a while ago now).